# Como remover uma Meta Tag criada por um plugin do WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Como posso fazer para remover uma meta tag no WordPress?

Mais precisamente a **meta tag** `generator` criada pelo **Visual Composer**.

```
<meta name="generator" content="Powered by Visual Composer - drag and drop page builder for WordPress."/>
```

Comment: Já experimentou comentar a linha que adiciona essa tag no *source* do plugin?

Comment: Como o Visual Composer é um plugin premium e com certeza vai ser complicado encontrar alguém que usa aqui e que saiba responder, eu acho que você deveria utilizar o seu direito de consumidor e falar com quem lhe vendeu ele no CodeCanyon, porque quando você compra você também ganha direito de ter suporte.

Comment: Podes postar o código do plugin que gera essa tag?

Comment: Já fucei e até agora não achei.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É necessário localizar o *hook* responsável por imprimir essa linha no HTML. Normalmente, é uma ação anexa ao `wp_head`. Depois disso, usamos [`remove_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) ou [`remove_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) para remover o *hook*.

Teremos que prestar atenção se o *hook* está dentro de outro e qual a prioridade de cada um. Se o plugin/tema usa algo assim:

```
add_action( $nome_do_hook, $funcao_de_retorno, $prioridade, $parametros );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'funcao_de_retorno', 11, 2 );
```

O `remove_action` vai ser:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'funcao_de_retorno', 11 );
```

Se a prioridade for `10` ou não estiver declarada, não é necessário colocá-la, pois 10 é o valor padrão. Os parametros não importam.

A coisa fica um pouco mais complexa quando o plugin usa OOP. Alguns programadores deixam os objetos anonimos, [causando este tipo de problema](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57079/how-to-remove-a-filter-that-is-an-anonymous-object/57088#57088). Mas, no caso do Visual Composer, é fácil acessar a classe:

```
add_action( 'init', function() 
{
    if( class_exists( 'WPBakeryVisualComposer') )
        remove_action( 'wp_head', array( WPBakeryVisualComposer::getInstance(), 'addMetaData' ) );
}, 11 ); // <-- a prioridade padrão não teve efeito, usando uma menos importante deu certo
```

Buscando por `Powered by` dentro dos arquivos do plugin, vemos que isso é adicionado por `$this->composer->addAction('wp_head', 'addMetaData');`, e esse código está dentro de um `init` com prioridade padrão.

Comment: Funcionou redondinho! Adicionei a um plugin com vários plugins `all in one` que você tem criado pra mim, rsrsrs.... Obrigado Bras! Você é 10.

Comment: Vou juntando vários em 1 só.

Comment: [Este plugin meu](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/many-tips-together) nasceu disso aí: juntando várias utilidades dentro de um só plugin ;)

Comment: Muito toop! Você é o cara!

Comment: Não conhecia esse plugin, genial!

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do @brasofilo estava correta, porém, parece que mudaram como cadastram a action e é preciso alterar de:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', array( WPBakeryVisualComposer::getInstance(), 'addMetaData' ) );
```

para:

```
remove_action('wp_head', array(visual_composer(), 'addMetaData'));
```

Comigo deu erro e encontrei essa solução no suporte deles na CodeCanyon.