# Alterar o meta robots WP

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Colegas.

Peguei um projeto do qual foi desenvolvido em WP. Infelizmente não sei mexer no WP, mas gostaria de alterar a linha:

```
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />
```

Dentro do arquivo header.php tem a linha:

```
wp_head();
```

Percebi que é dentro dele que está o meta, mas quando procurei em functions.php, não encontrei essa função.

Ele tem o próprio tema e a versão é 3.3.2. Sei que é uma versão antiga, mas em março temos o planejamento de trocar de site.

Answer (score 2):

Nas referencias do WP tem as seguintes funções:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

  - Existe desde a versão 1.2.0
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/

  - Existe desde a versão 1.2.0
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/noindex/

  - Existe desde a versão 2.1.0

Veja que no segundo link tem isso:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'noindex' );
```

Então se isso adiciona, para remover creio que seja algo como:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'noindex');
```

E se quiser adicionar a sua `<meta>` customizada, deve ser algo como:

```
function metaindexexemplo() {
     //Escreva seu meta customizado aqui
     echo '<meta ....>';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'metaindexexemplo');
```

Aqui tem uma resposta relacionada que explica bem:

- [Como remover uma Meta Tag criada por um plugin do WordPress?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28232/3635)